# Headers X-XSS-Protection issue

Tags: linux, php, xss, hsts, header

I want to clear my doubt that Is there any issues coming from adding 'Strict-Transport-Security' and 'X-XSS-Protection' headers ?

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400;
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
```

I didn't put 'include SubDomains' for the HSTS header because I wasn't sure if we always want those over HTTPS. Specifically I could see this causing issues with HubSpot and/or CDN pages (slowing down the CDN delivery, not resolution issues).

modern browsers may not even implement XSS filtering right ?

if im not wrong Modern browsers prefer this right ? `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy`

Our WAF will block XSS injections as well so the header wouldn't actually come into effect.

what is the best advise here ?

Comment: You should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection because there's no use in repeating the entire content here.

Comment: ok, is CSP policy will help ? what is your advise here !

Comment: Did you read this: "These [`X-XSS-Protection`] protections are largely unnecessary in modern browsers when sites implement a strong `Content-Security-Policy` that disables the use of inline JavaScript (`'unsafe-inline'`)." Which part of this was unclear?